# Hamiltonian cycle that contains a specified edge in a 3-connected cubic bipartite planar Hamiltonian graph

Tags: planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

Assume that we have a 3-connected cubic bipartite planar graph with a Hamiltonian cycle. That graph must have at least 4 Hamiltonian cycles, because of Theorem 1 and Theorem 10 of this [paper](http://www.akcejournal.org/contents/vol4no3/vol4no3-3.pdf).

I would like to know whether every edge of that graph is contained in at least one Hamiltonian cycle. It seems true for small 3-connected cubic bipartite planar graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Theorem 2.5 (on page [71](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FzRHBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA71&ots=aLxsQg43eB&dq=hamiltonian%20cycle%20edge%20cover%20barnette%20graph&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q&f=false)) of Mathematical Combinatorics, Vol. 3/2014: international book series, what I'm asking for is true if and only if Barnette's conjecture holds true.